# Where can I share my game?

Tags: distribution

I am looking for places on the web to share my game.

I'm relatively new to game development. Not looking to 'promote' my game or sell it. Just want to share it in places where there is a possibility people will download and play it.

Are there any sites that are meant to share indie games? And in general any site where I can post a download to my game will be great.

Thanks

Comment: Specify the platform of your game. There are a few sites like this for web games (ie. Flash or Unity games played in a browser) but I don't know about downloadable games.

Comment: It's a downloadable 2D game in Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are the sites I hang around:

[TIGSource Forums](http://forums.tigsource.com/index.php) - Even though it isn't the best community in my opinion, it still is a great way to share your games and get some critical(and sometimes crappy) feedback from other developers.

[GameDev Forums](https://www.gamedev.net/) - Another good place to get great feedback on your game. I think you might have more luck here, on the critiscm end than at TIGSource

[Kongregate](http://www.kongregate.com/) - Another site which has an awesome community. They also host web games(with monetization opportunities  - so it's another great way to get feedback and some monetary reward as well!

[GameJolt](http://gamejolt.com/) - Friendly Developers and Players, even though the developers can become a bit rowdy sometimes. A lot of friendships were made here and again, it's a great place to share your game - even if it is not web-based.

[r/GameDev](http://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/) - Who doesn't like Reddit? ;) Another great way to share and communicate with other developers.

[IndieDB](http://www.indiedb.com/forum) - This is, perhaps, the best way for you to share your game to a large audience of players(and developers - who are secretly disguised as players). The forums are great and they have a nice way of letting people rate your game and leave reviews accordingly!

[Our Chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development) - This site's chat is a really awesome place to be if you want to share your game and get feedback in "realtime". I frequent this myself and it's a great place to share screenshots/builds and get into intense technical discussions. An the occasional tom-foolery/drama/emotional outbreaks. ;)

[Indie Game Forums](http://indiegamer.com) - As they put it on their web site: *"[...] a diverse community has grown out of a passion for creating great games. Here you will find over 10 years of in-depth discussion on game design, the business of game development, and marketing/sales. Indie Gamer also provides a friendly place to meet up with other Developers, Artists, Composers and Writers. "*

Social Networks like Twitter and Facebook are also great ways to share your games. Facebook has a group devoted to game developers. Twitter has a #gamedev hashtag as well as #screenshotsaturday tag if you're looking to get exposure as well as feedback.

Oh, and there's also the IRC channels! I don't IRC too much, but I'd recommend the #reddit-gamedev channel on irc.freenode.net.

Comment: I think the OP wants to know websites where he can host the game file and people can find it and download it for free, as opposed to forums where he can share the link.